# when do you use Object.defineProperty()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm wondering when I should use

```
Object.defineProperty
```

to create new properties for an object. I'm aware that I'm able to set things like

```
enumerable: false
```

but when do you need this really? If you just set a property like

```
myObject.myprop = 5;
```

its descriptors are all set to true, right? I'm actually more curious when you guys use that rather verbose call to .defineProperty() and for what reasons.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is mainly used to set properties with specific property descriptors (e.g. read-only (constants), enumerability (to not show a property in a [`for (.. in ..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, getters, setters).

```
"use strict";
var myObj = {}; // Create object
// Set property (+descriptor)
Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'myprop', {
    value: 5,
    writable: false
});
console.log(myObj.myprop);// 5
myObj.myprop = 1;         // In strict mode: TypeError: myObj.myprop is read-only
```

### Example

This method extends the `Object` prototype with a property. Only the getter is defined, and the enumerability is set to `false`.

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, '__CLASS__', {
    get: function() {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(this);
    },
    enumerable: false // = Default
});
Object.keys({});           // []
console.log([].__CLASS__); // "[object Array]"
```

Comment: ok I understand that.  But does this makes sense? Most of the time I want all descriptors set to true, so I can just setup properties the old fashion way right? Is there any other advantage for .defineProperty?

Comment: @RobW: you can also create `getters` and `setters` without using `.defineProperty`.

Comment: @jAndy But the property will be exposed in a `for (.. in ..)` loop: `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__('lol',function(){return 3});for(var i in [])alert(i);` shows `"lol"`. `Object.defineProperty` can be used to define a getter/setter which *also* does **not** show up in `for (.. in ..)` loops.

Comment: @RobW: I was more thinking about using `var foo = { get lol() { return 5;} };`, but the issue remains the same.

Comment: @Andre: If you don't see a use case for them, then you don't need them... when you need them, you will know ;)

Comment: can anyone tell me how do you use 'set' how does it work like this or this. Assume x={}, and i have used defineproperty and set prop b and am using 'set'SOOOOOO.... 1st: x.b=2; 2 goes to 'set' then it does something to it and then store it or 2nd: 2 goes to value but also get passed to set function. 
Is there a way to access/redefine/define value that is being stored before it gets stored just using set.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Have a look at this example: https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

Comment: `writable: false` is sort of like `Object.freeze()`, but for a specific , no?

Answer (score 30):

Features like 'enumerable' are rarely used in my experience.
The major use case is computed properties:

```
var myObj = {};

myObj.width = 20;
myObj.height = 20;

Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'area', {
    get: function() {
        return this.width*this.height;
    }
});
console.log(myObj.area);
```

Comment: Seems to me like your going out of your way to make that a property all in the name of a very grey area in semantics;

Comment: @aaaaaa what? grey area?

Comment: I just don't understand the use case for providing a calculated property as opposed to simply making it a function.  e.g. myObj.area = function() { return this.width * this.height; }

Comment: The function is completely valid, but there may be use cases where you prefer a property over a function.

Comment: The primary use would be that, rather than having two separate functions (ex: getFoo(), setFoo()), you can define a single property with a getter / setter that wraps custom logic and then simply use standard assignment operators on a single member (ex: x = myObj.Foo or myObj.Foo = x). This makes your code simpler and also is useful when you want to prevent a value from being emitted when serializing to JSON. (ex: your object has a bunch of UI-specific properties you don't want sent over the wire...) All in all, this helps JS more closely follow standard OO principles

Answer (score 20):

A really good reason for using Object.defineProperty is that it lets you loop through a function in an object as a computed property, which executes the function instead of returning the function's body.

For example:

```
var myObj = {};

myObj.width = 20;
myObj.height = 20;

Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'area', {
    get: function() {
        return this.width*this.height;
    },
    enumerable: true
});

for (var key in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + myObj[key]);
  }
}
//width -> 20, height -> 20, area -> 400
```

Versus adding the function as a property to an object literal:

```
var myObj = {};

myObj.width = 20;
myObj.height = 20;

myObj.area = function() {
       return this.width*this.height;
    };

for (var key in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + myObj[key]);
  }
}
// width -> 20, height -> 20, area -> function() { return this.width*this.height;}
```

Make sure you set the enumerable property to true in order to loop through it.

Comment: Same `for-in problem` for direct `Object.prototype.area` without Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'area' ...

Answer (score 6):

For example, [that's how Vue.js keeps track of changes in the `data` object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked):

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its `data` option, Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them to `getter/setters` using **`Object.defineProperty`**. This is an ES5-only and un-shimmable feature, which is why Vue doesn’t support IE8 and below.
>
> The getter/setters are invisible to the user, but under the hood they enable Vue to perform dependency-tracking and change-notification when properties are accessed or modified.
>
> [...]

Keep in mind that even a super slim and basic version of Vue.js would use something more than just `Object.defineProperty`, but the main functionality comes from it:

[image: Vue.js's Reactivity Cycle]

Here you can see an article where the author implements a minimal PoC version of something like Vue.js: https://medium.com/js-dojo/understand-vue-reactivity-implementation-step-by-step-599c3d51cd6c

And here a talk (in Spanish) where the speaker builds something similar while explaining reactivity in Vue.js: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axXwWU-L7RM

Answer (score 5):

### Summary:

In Javascript Objects are collections of key-value pairs. 
`Object.defineProperty()` is a function which can define a new property on an object and can set the following attributes  of a property:

- **value `<any>`:** The value associated with the key
- **writable `<boolean>`:** if writable is set to `true` The property can be updated by assigning a new value to it. If set to `false` you can't change the value.
- **enumerable `<boolean>`:** if enumerable is set to `true` Property can be accessed via a `for..in` loop. Furthermore are the only the enumerable property keys returned with `Object.keys()`
- **configurable `<boolean>`:** If configurable is set to `false` you cannot change change the property attributes (value/writable/enumerable/configurable), also since you cannot change the value you cannot delete it using the `delete` operator.

### Example:

```js
let obj = {};


Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop1', {
      value: 1,
      writable: false,
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: false
});   // create a new property (key=prop1, value=1)


Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop2', {
      value: 2,
      writable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
});  // create a new property (key=prop2, value=2)


console.log(obj.prop1, obj.prop2); // both props exists

for(const props in obj) {
  console.log(props);
  // only logs prop2 because writable is true in prop2 and false in prop1
}


obj.prop1 = 100;
obj.prop2 = 100;
console.log(obj.prop1, obj.prop2);
// only prop2 is changed because prop2 is writable, prop1 is not


delete obj.prop1;
delete obj.prop2;

console.log(obj.prop1, obj.prop2);
// only prop2 is deleted because prop2 is configurable and prop1 is not
```

Answer (score 5):

`Object.defineProperty` **prevents you from accidentally assigning values to some key in its prototype chain**. With this method you assign only to that particular object level(not to any key in prototype chain).

For example: 
            There is an object like `{key1: value1, key2: value2}` and you don't know exactly its prototype chain or by mistake you miss it and there is some property 'color' somewhere in prototype chain then-

**using dot(.) assignment-**

**this operation will assign value to key 'color' in prototype chain**(if key exist somewhere) and you will find the object with no change as .
obj.color= 'blue'; // obj remain same as {key1: value1, key2: value2}

**using Object.defineProperty method**-

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'color', {
  value: 'blue'
});
```

// now obj looks like `{key1: value1, key2: value2, color: 'blue'}`. it adds property to the same level.Then you can iterate safely with method `Object.hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: Anish congratulations on your first answer. A very detailed explanation.  You may find syntax highlighting helpful in your answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 3):

One neat use case I have seen for `defineProperty` is for libraries to provide an error property to the user which, if it's not accessed within a certain interval you would log the error yourself. For example:

```
let logErrorTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Unhandled (in <your library>)', error.stack || error);
  }
}, 10);

Object.defineProperty(data, 'error', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: () => {
      clearTimeout(logErrorTimeoutId);
      return error;
    },
  });
```

Source for this code: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/ddd3d8faabf135dca691d20ce8ab0bc24ccc414e/src/graphql.tsx#L510

Answer (score 1):

A good use is when you need to do some interception or apply a classical Observer/Observable pattern in a elegant way:

https://www.monterail.com/blog/2016/how-to-build-a-reactive-engine-in-javascript-part-1-observable-objects

Comment: Check my answer, there was an interesting talk about this back in March at `t3chfest` 

Answer (score 0):

A very useful case is to monitor changes to something and act on them. It's easy because you can have callback functions fire whenever the value gets set. Here's a basic example.

You have an object `Player` that can be playing or not playing. You want something to happen right when it starts playing, and right when it stops playing.

```
function Player(){}
Object.defineProperty(Player.prototype, 'is_playing', {
  get(){
    return this.stored_is_playing;  // note: this.is_playing would result in an endless loop
  },
  set(newVal){
    this.stored_is_playing = newVal;
    if (newVal === true) {
      showPauseButton();
    } else {
      showPlayButton();
    }
  }
});
const cdplayer = new Player();
cdplayer.is_playing = true; // showPauseButton fires
```

This answer is related to a couple other answers here, which are good stepping points for more information, but with no need to follow external links to read about libraries or programming paradigms.

Answer (score -2):

@Gerard Simpson

If 'area' should be enumerable it can be written without Object.defineProperty, too.

```
var myObj = {
    get area() { return this.width * this.height }
};

myObj.width = 20;
myObj.height = 20;

for (var key in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + myObj[key]);
  }
}

//area -> 400, width -> 20, height -> 20
```