# Javascript - Difference between defineProperty and directly defining a function on an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, koa, defineproperty

I recently created my own module for node.js for use with the koa module. It's a translation module like koa-i18n. I've studied other koa modules to see how functions/properties are applied to the koa context/request and some of them use the Object.defineProperty function, but what I did in my module was apply a function directly on 'this'.

So, what is the difference between using

```
Object.defineProperty(app.context, 'getSomeValue', { ... });
```

and

```
return function* (next) { this.getSomeValue = function () { ... } }
```

I've also come across the node-delegates module which uses the 'apply' function.
Which of these methods is the preferred way of applying a function/property to an existing object and what are the pros and cons?

Comment: Generally there are no pros and cons neither is one preferred. They all are for different purpose. If you want to have a property that is readonly or that is not enumerable then you need to use `defineProperty`. Same it with the other techniques. Some might be equal, and you might use the one over the other because of consistency.

Comment: Alright, so using 'this.getSomeValue' is read-write and could be overwritten by another module which also defines the same property name on 'this'?

Comment: The way you wrote it is a syntax error anyway. But as long as you don't use `Object.defineProperty(app.context, 'getSomeValue', { writable:false, value: someValue });` then the property `getSomeValue`  of `app.context` can be overwritten any other js code. If you really should enforce `writable:false`  depends on the situation, in most cases you will only want to do that for constants.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Thanks for explaining. One more thing. `this` has a `state` property. How would one use the `defineProperty` function on `this.state` and define a function? `this.state` is defined in the source code as `context.state = {}`

Comment: While this kind of question is highly OT because it is really broad, you should think over why you want to use `defineProperty`  instead of just using `context.state.someFunction = function() {}`.

Comment: Just for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Um, `return function* (next) { this.getSomeValue() { ... } }`  is not creating a property at all? Is that really the snippet you want us to compare against `definedProperty`?

Comment: Voted up - Good question!

Comment: @Bergi, it does. `this` is the koa context object. The generator function just returns a generator middleware and inside the function `this` is bound to the koa context object.

Comment: @Supercell: no, it does not *create a property* - as you say, it `return`s a function! There is no assignment whatsoever.

Comment: My bad, the syntax is all wrong. It should be `this.getSomeValue = function () { .. }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defineProperty method has specific advantages over directly setting a property in an object or returning a function object (which in some ways can simulate pesudo-private fields).

You can use defineProperty to define constants decide whether they are enumerable and more.

You can check-out a similar discussion here - [when do you use Object.defineProperty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105824/when-do-you-use-object-defineproperty).

Also do check out the examples from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for this method and the configs for being able to decide whether the prop is writable, enumerable etc using define property.

Apply is a bit different and I think a better comparison would be with the JavaScript call method. It is similar to [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) with mostly schematic differences. See note here. Apply and Call can be used in a way to invoke a method - roughly like reflection in other languages like Java.