# Why do we use Object.defindProperty() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have seen in youtube videos about js that the speaker was using:

```
const hero = {
    health:10
}
Object.defineProperty(hero, 'status', {
    get(){
        if(this.health > 50){
            return 'fit like a champ';
        }else {
            return 'badly hurt';
        }
    }
});

console.log(hero.status)
```

to assign new keys to objects based on condition but we can also use it in this way:

```
if(hero.health>50){
    hero.status = 'good'
}else {
    hero.status='bad'
}
console.log(hero.status)
```

I want to know which is the better approach and the best practice.
Thanks

Comment: already answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105824/when-do-you-use-object-defineproperty

Comment: the defineProperty example is basically a read-only property ... that one reason to use that method